# Secure some routes with NavController in ionic2

Tags: ionic2

In angular2, I can set guards on routes, and using the hierarchy of route definition, I can setup a role based guards system.

But in ionic2, it uses NavController of navigation. The NavController has a `ionViewCanEnter` to control whether user can enter a page. But it seems that I need to add it in all pages. Can I can not find anything about the navigation control with page hierarchy or something like that.

So, how can I implement the role based guards with ionic2? Thanks.